# WSL: Using A WSL symlink folder from Windows

Tags: symlink, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use WSL almost exclusively, and only switch to main windows for browsing and running Windows native programs. I have a git repository located at `/mnt/c/myrepo`. In order to "install" the code inside `/mnt/c/myrepo` I need to move it to `/mnt/c/otherlocation/renamed`. Instead of executing `cp -r /mnt/c/myrepo /mnt/c/otherlocation/renamed` every time I do a `git pull` from `/mnt/c/myrepo`, I would like to symlink `/mnt/c/myrepo` to `/mnt/c/otherlocation/renamed`. However when I do this, the program which consumes `/mnt/c/otherlocation/renamed` isn't able to view the "contents" of renamed as a directory.

I have been all over the WSL github repo and issue tracker trying to find a solution to this issue. I see a lot of exclamations about how symlinks "just work". I have enabled every Windows 10 developer feature I can find, I even followed some reddit thread where someone claimed that purchasing Pengwin and creating a symlink from Pengwin would ensure this compatibility, but I still can't seem to make this work.

The basic usage I need, is allow me to view "renamed" as a directory from windows, or for windows to recognize the symlink as a symlinked directory.

from wsl:

```
ln -s /mnt/c/myrepo  /mnt/c/otherlocation/renamed
```

from windows:

1. open file explorer
2. navigate to c:\otherlocation
3. open mydir and view the contents as if it were a native directory

How do I do this?

Comment: Apparently, the correct answer is that the symlink path must be relative. From `otherlocation` the command is `ln -s ../myrepo ./renamed`

Comment: Using relative paths doesn't work for me either, also, I have this issue in WSL/Windows 11 but not in WSL/Windows 10

Answer (score 18):

Do the symlink in Windows, in cmd.exe:

```
mklink /d C:\otherlocation\renamed C:\myrepo
```

It doesn't make sense creating the symlinks in WSL if both directories are in Windows.

This symlink will work in WSL as well.

Comment: This appears to work for local paths, but UNC paths and mapped drives just give "Input/output error" when you try to access them in WSL.

Comment: Give me an example

Comment: I used `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "C:\path\to\your\renamed" -Target "C:\path\to\original"` in Powershell rather. It supports UNC paths so I used this to symlink a \\wsl$\ubuntu\var\www\ directory to allow PowerShell to navigate to it and run npm from windows.

Comment: Since Powershell doesn't support relative paths with New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink , it's easiest to invoke cmd from Powershell, eg `cmd /c mklink /d native windows-amd64` . This will create a link that works in WSL, too. Remember to elevate your shell or use the fancy config to avoid needing to elevate.

Answer (score 14):

The solution to this problem is simply to use the relative path when declaring the link. If you want to link from windows to windows, you should relatively path from the current directory and then you can link anywhere you wish.

From the example, instead of this:

```
ln -s /mnt/c/myrepo  /mnt/c/otherlocation/renamed
```

Do this:

```
cd /mnt/c/otherlocation
ln -s ../../myrepo ./renamed
```

Comment: That doesn't appear work for me using wsl2 and windows 11.    The symlink works as expected within WSL2, but is invalid in Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work as well. Windows displays symlinks as invalid junctions. It's not possible to neither step into them or get information about them.

Answer (score 5):

Since this seems to be the only SO post that has any googlejuice when searching for **Symlink from Windows to WSL** I thought I'd add the answer to that question, ie,

*how to make a "symlink" from the windows filesystem to the wsl filesystem, that works for windows apps?*

answer was in the comments, credit to @Mikepote

1. first open **Powershell** with **Run as Administrator**
2. then run

```
 New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "windows-path\to\symlink" -Target "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\yourusername\path\to\target-thing"
```

substitute your distro name for `Ubuntu` above if necessary, and `yourusername` obviously too.

Comment: Unfortunately, while this answer works when making a symbolic link in a Windows directory that targets a WSL directory, attempting to do it the other direction errors out with "New-Item: Symbolic links are not supported for the specified path." in Windows 11. That is, `-Target "windows\path" -Path "\\wsl$\Ubuntu\path"` will fail. (Btw, your use of "from" and "to" originally made me think you were talking about the reverse, but rather than argue those semantics, I'll just point out the issue with as clear language as I can)

Comment: This also does not help when one receives a large software package (parhaps as a tarball or even a repo) that is Linux based and contains lots of soft links inside it. Being able to copy that out of the Linux (WSL) environment so that it is in the Windows (NTFS) environment has eluded me for a while. [this is different than the case where things are create i the Wndows environment]

Answer (score 0):

Creating a hard link between directories using `cmd` with administrator privileges worked for me:

```
mklink /J C:\Users\NameNoSpace "C:\Users\Name With Spaces"
```

Comment: /J creates a directory-junction (like /H for files) which is NOT symbolic (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) .. also put "name with spaces in doublequotes"

Comment: Quite right, thanks, corrected

Answer (score 0):

If the folder is in a drive, the latter can be mounted inside WSL:

```bash
mkdir /mnt/z
mount -t drvfs Z: /mnt/z
```

`/etc/fstab` can be updated accordingly.